# fiware orion broker entity deletion

Tags: fiware-orion

I am trying to delete entity of a type from the database, this error keeps coming up Failed to delete entity 826578. Status code: 409
{"error":"TooManyResults","description":"More than one matching entity. Please refine your query"}
No more entities to delete.
Any suggestion on how to go about this is well appreciated.

I tried specifying the id and type of entity to delete, but the error kept popping up.

Comment: Please edit your question post to include the request (verb + URL + payload) you are using to delete the entity. With that information, I'd be able to provide a possible solution.